# Cloud Datalab zombie VM

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I had a play with Cloud Datalab a few days ago. After I finished I deleted the VM in my list which was named `gae-datalab-main-[..]`

It successfully deleted.

A couple of days later I noticed back in my list of VMs. So I deleted it again thinking it was just a glitch.

But it's back again today:

[image]
[image]

Anyone know what's going on here?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about the trouble you are having. Did you delete it from the App Engine --> Versions page? Here is a quick screenshot:

[image: Delete App Engine Module/Version as shown]

Comment: Thanks Dinesh. I wasn't aware you had to delete it from there. I just saw the VM and thought if I delete that then I'm all done!

Comment: And note that you can also stop/restart the instance instead of completely deleting it -- see more details at https://cloud.google.com/datalab/getting-started